# how to set value in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn from a datatable?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvcb = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)grvPackList.Columns["Units"];
                Globals.G_ProductUtility G_Utility = new Globals.G_ProductUtility();
                dgvcb.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton;
                G_Utility.addUnittoComboDGV(dgvcb);
                DataSet _ds = iRawMaterialsRequest.Select();
                grvPackList.DataSource = _ds.Tables[0];
```

the problem is that the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in the datagrid is not selected with the value in table how is it possilbe to set value of DataGridViewComboBoxColumn from datasoure

```
int i=0;
                foreach (DataRow dgvr in  _ds.Tables[0].Rows )
                {
                    grvPackList.Rows[i].Cells["Units"].Value = dgvr["Units"].ToString();
                    i++;
                }
```

this code is working but is there any solution with out using loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i=0; 
 foreach (DataRow dgvr in  _ds.Tables[0].Rows )
                {
                    grvPackList.Rows[i].Cells["Units"].Value = dgvr["Units"].ToString();
                    i++;
                }
```

When i Tried this it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

you can bind the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn directly to your datasouce like

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvcb = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)grvPackList.Columns["Units"];
dgvcb.ValueMember = "YourUnitValue"; 
dgvcb.DisplayMember = "Units";
dgvcb.DataSource = _ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Without setting `ValueMember`, it WILL fail.